How to convert base64format to the word document preview in angular
Does in angular do we have any library ?
i was looking for some examples but i didn't found any.
I have found a library ngx-doc-viewer it has a url but i have base64 which i need to transform to word document. So i'm looking for some better solution.
 
 convertAndDownload(base64Data: string, fileName: string) {
    const byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/msword' });
    saveAs(blob, fileName + '.doc');
  }

Above code has saveAs method but i'm looking for some preview of word document.

You can pass the blob into the createObjectURL(blob). Does this help you?
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'document.docx';  // The name of the downloaded file
link.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);

IF YOU DON'T WANT TO DONWLOAD THEN
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);

After downloading the file you can remove the file from the DOM.
document.body.removeChild(link);


I don't want to download the file instead i want to preview the doc file in the same view

You can try this
"const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);"

If you don't want to open then you can add that URL in the Iframe.
